# Displaying corresponding value of a column by matching it to value of the second column

Tags: r, match, lattice

Generated two datasets as below:

```
  H<-data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:20,10,rep=TRUE)))  
  G<-data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:20,10,rep=TRUE)))  
  H[c(2,3,7,9),9]<-NA
  G[c(1,5,7,8),9]<-NA
  H$diff<-H$X10-H$X9
  G$diff<-G$X10-G$X9
  H$perc<-round((H$diff/H$X10)*100,1)
  G$perc<-round((G$diff/G$X10)*100,1)
```

Created a plot using:

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(X8+X9+X10~X1,H,type=c('p','l','g'),
col = c('yellow', 'green', 'blue','red'),
ylab='Count',layout=c(3, 1), 
xlab=paste("H",'difference',min(pmin(H$perc, na.rm = TRUE),na.rm=TRUE),
'% change count'))
```

I'm trying to get the code to display the value of corresponding difference from the "diff" column and the value from X2 column, along with the lowest difference (which is what the min function is doing). I've tried using "match" in vain. Could someone help please?

Comment: Not sure about the expected result. Perhaps `H$diff[which.min(H$perc)]`

Comment: Thanks, yeah this does the work well. I've extended it to include more than one value.

Comment: You said you need the lowest difference.  Can you elaborate on more than one value comment?

Comment: i mean your solution allows me to display H$diff that corresponds to the minimum value of H$perc. I'm including another column H$X2 as well that corresponds to min value of H$perc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can try

```
ind <- which.min(H$perc)
label1 <- paste0("H difference ", H$diff[ind], "% change count")
label2 <- paste('X2 value', H$X2[ind])
xyplot(X8+X9+X10~X1,H,type=c('p','l','g'),
col = c('yellow', 'green', 'blue','red'),
ylab='Count',layout=c(3, 1), 
xlab=paste(label1, label2, sep=", "))
```

#### Update

If you have multiple datasets, create a function

```
labelfn <- function(dat, Col1, Col2, diffCol){
  args <- as.list(match.call())[-1]
  e1 <- eval(args$Col1, dat)
  e2 <- eval(args$Col2, dat)
  e3 <- eval(args$diffCol, dat)
  ind <- which.min(e1)
  label1 <- paste0(deparse(args[[1]]), ' difference ', 
           e3[ind], '% change count')
  label2 <- paste(deparse(args[[3]]), ' value', e2[ind])
  paste(label1, label2, sep=", ")
 }

 labelfn(G, perc, X2, diff)
 #[1] "G difference -14% change count, X2  value 5"
  labelfn(H, perc, X2, diff)
 #[1] "H difference -2% change count, X2  value 18"
```

Comment: Thanks akrun, that is what I ended up doing but instead of creating label 1 and label 2, I simply put that in xlab= paste. either way, if the data changes I'll have to make manual adjustments to the labels etc one way or another. Another way I was looking at extending this was, since I have more than 2 datasets and each will have a similar plot minus the dataspecific information that needs to be fed to the plot, I could create a function, albeit extremely complex, that would look at the key columns, names, data required to generate the plot.

Comment: @oivemaria I created the `labels` for more clarity. Creating a function would be easier.  In that case, you may need to change `$` to `[` and the arguments accordingly.

Comment: @oivemaria Updated with a function